# Sync jQuery calendar with Google Calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-api

I have a jQuery calendar widget and I want to sync it with the present user's Google Calendar. Do jQuery and Google Calendar allows this? If so please let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Calendar API documentation is very good:

[Google Calendar API Javascript: Authentication](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_js.html#Authenticating)

You will find numerous examples further down the page.